# How to pass functions by reference

Tags: function, swift, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Create a function that takes an array of integers, a function passed by reference which will perform an operation on the array and return an Int result.

I had issues. After much searching to no avail, I broke the problem into pieces of code to test each piece in isolation.

My simple "pass function by reference code" is:

```
func counter(start:Int)->String{
  for var i = 0 ; i<start; ++i{
    println("I => \(i)")
  }
  return "Done"
}

func test(i:Int, inout f:(Int)->String){
  f(i)
}

test(5,&counter)
```

The problem is, even my simple test to pass a function by reference fails with:

```
(Int)->String is not convertible to @lvalue inout $T3
```

If I do this:

```
func counter(end:Int)->String{
  for var i = 0 ; i<end; ++i{
    println("I => \(i)")
  }
  return "Done"
}

func test(i:Int, inout f:(Int)->String){
  f(i)
}

var f1 = counter
test(5,&f1)//pass a reference as an argument to the function
```

Is this pass by reference? As this works I'm not sure this is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the parameters and return types match, just pass the function as it is.

You don't need the `&...` at all.

Comment: Hi Helen, yes the above does work but unless functions when passed to another function as an argument are passed by reference in Swift, then I'm not really doing the exercise as the book stated; i.e. _create a function that returns an integer and takes an array of integers and a reference to a function as arguments. This new function should apply the supplied function to the array and return the result_.

Answer (score 1):

First, passing by reference (`inout`) is for cases where for example you need to assign to the parameter inside the called function and have it be assigned to the passed variable in the calling scope, or where you need to call a `mutating` method on it and have it be reflected in the calling scope, etc.

You are not assigning to `f` inside `test`. Therefore, it is pointless to make it `inout`, as it restricts what can be passed to it.

To answer technically why you get an error, the answer is that you cannot pass by reference a constant variable (i.e. `let`), and `counter` is a constant variable (you cannot assign to `counter`). You can think of the `func` syntax for defining a function at the top level as similar to a `let` with a closure expression:

```
func counter(start:Int)->String{ ... }
```

is like

```
let counter : Int->String = { (start:Int)->String in ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer newacct. Sorry to pester you more but could you explain how you do pass a function by reference to another function in Swift please?

Comment: @Mortoman: You would do the same thing you did. But the variable you pass by reference must be a variable declared with `var`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that `inout f:(Int)->String` is not of the same function type as your `counter()` function. If you remove the `inout` keyword from the `test` function and the `&` in the function call, everything works fine.

Are you sure the exercise isn't asking you to pass the array by reference?

Comment: Hi, yes the exercise is from the SAMs book "learn swift in 24 hours" and specifically requests the following... _create a function that returns an integer and takes an array of integers and a reference to a function as arguments. This new function should apply the supplied function to the array and return the result_.

Comment: Ah ... I'm willing to bet that the book is using the term "reference" non-technically in this case. It's not telling you to pass a function by reference, but rather to create one function, and then create another function that will take it as a parameter. The function name you pass in as a parameter would be the "reference" in this case, though again, not in strict technical terms. You can't pass functions by reference in Swift. It's simply not possible. There is no such thing as an `inout` function parameter.